# assigning awk result into variable

Tags: awk

I want to assign this command output into variable

```
echo "status:0
id:239965eb20557679348-1
aaa:[bbb:config this
ccc:0.758]" | awk -F: 'NR==3 {print $3}'
```

but when I try with many method to `echo $my_var`, I've got failed with blank result,

```
my_var=$(echo "status:0
id:239965eb20557679348-1
aaa:[bbb:config this
ccc:0.758]" | awk -F: 'NR==3 {print $3}')
```

nor

```
my_var=`echo "status:0
id:239965eb20557679348-1
aaa:[bbb:config this
ccc:0.758]" | awk -F: 'NR==3 {print $3}'`
```

has failed with no luck, is there something I missing for this?

Comment: Works for me.  Both print `config this`.

Comment: Did you have newlines in your `echo`?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  As written, the code should work fine, setting `$my_var` to `config this`; it does for me, at any rate.  I can't think of many ways that you could miswrite what you've written in the question and still get nothing (no error message, no unexpected command executed, ...).  How are you testing for the result?  What are you seeing?  Are you by any mischance using a C shell derivative?

Comment: my expected result is<br/>
shell#> echo $my_var<br/>
config this

Comment: Did you remove a backslash from the code in the question at any point?

Comment: yes I have remove the "\" from all

Comment: I can make it in the direct shell, but failed when I put it in the filescript with bash

Answer (score 0):

I removed NR==3 from the code and its working fine

```
my_var=`echo "status:0 id:239965eb20557679348-1 aaa:[bbb:config this ccc:0.758]" | awk -F: '{print $3}'`
```

Also when i changed the NR==3 to NR=3 it works too

```
my_var=`echo "status:0 id:239965eb20557679348-1 aaa:[bbb:config this ccc:0.758]" | awk -F: 'NR=3{print $3}'`
```

Comment: Think about what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

You have accidently added `\` in the 3rd attempt. Just remove that; it would work.

```
$ val=`echo "status:0 
id:239965eb20557679348-1
aaa:[bbb:config this
ccc:0.758]" | awk -F: 'NR==3 { print $3 } '`
$ echo $val
config this 
$
```

Comment: There is a stray backslash?  It isn't visible in either the original or the edited version of the question...

Comment: Actually user might ahve removed that now !

Comment: Well, I suppose it might have been changed in the first five minutes, while edits "don't count".  There is no evidence still available that shows it, but you must be right that it was there.  And if the backslash was present at the end of either the 'config this' line or the previous line, you'd be absolutely right that there'd be no output, and that removing the backslash would fix the problem.

Comment: Actually, the location of the backslash alters the answers; when on the 'config this' line, the output is 'config thisccc', but when on the other line, you get a blank line because line 3 has only two fields and printing the third generates an empty string and a newline.

Comment: yes it's work for direct script to shell, but not working when I put in file (I'm using bash)
<br/>
adi@adi-laptop:~/voice$ more test<br/>
#!/bin/bash<br/>

valu=`echo "status:0<br/>
id:239965eb20557679348-1<br/>
aaa:[bbb:config this<br/>
ccc:0.758]" | awk -F: 'NR==3 {print $3}'`<br/>
adi@adi-laptop:~/voice$ ./test<br/>
adi@adi-laptop:~/voice$ echo $valu<br/>
<br/>
adi@adi-laptop:~/voice$<br/>

Comment: looks like I miss understanding script behavior.
after script running, it's variable was missing, but if I put echo command inside file script, it's show the variable value.
BTW thanks a lot all.

Answer (score 0):

If something works on the command line but not in a script, the answer is almost always that there's something preceding it in the script that's causing the failure. Do this:

```
$ cat -v script
$ ./script
```

and copy/paste the result into your question so we can see what's really going on.